# Disable dapper.rainbow from using ID while inserting

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, dapper-rainbow

I am using dapper.rainbow for inserting a record into MSSQL db. Following is my code

```
int? id  = db.RoomTypes.Insert(roomType)
```

When i run my app, i am getting the below exception.

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'RoomTypes' 
when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I think that dapper.rainbow is using the value (default value for int) for my Identity Column during the insert. This is what causing this exception. My identity column for the table `RoomTypes` is auto incremented and it is also the primary key of my table.

Now, how do i stop the dapper.rainbow from using the ID column during insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Dapper.Rainbow.Insert](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper.Rainbow/Database.cs) method, the method is "dumb" to the type passed in as the data parameter:

```
public virtual int? Insert(dynamic data)
{
    var o = (object)data;
    List<string> paramNames = GetParamNames(o);

    string cols = string.Join(",", paramNames);
    string cols_params = string.Join(",", paramNames.Select(p => "@" + p));
    var sql = "set nocount on insert " + TableName + " (" + cols + ") values (" + cols_params + ") select cast(scope_identity() as int)";

    return database.Query<int?>(sql, o).Single();
}
```

In other words, if you include the ID as a property in the parameter, then Dapper will try to insert that value into the database. And as you've seen, if you have IDENTITY_INSERT set to Off, then the insert will fail.

This means you'll need to create a new type that doesn't include your ID property to pass into the method. A few of ideas come to mind:

1. Create a base class without the ID for `RoomTypes` and then just pass in the base class to the `Insert` method.
2. Create a dynamic parameter and pass that to the `Insert` method with only the properties you want to insert into the database.
3. Override the `Insert` method and remove the ID parameter before sending to the `Dapper`

Comment: thanks.. i used the dynamic parameter, by this way i can exclude created and modified fields too.

Comment: I don't get this. Looking at the same source now, I see `paramNames.Remove("Id");`, and it says 'last change 5 Dec 2012' - when that line was added. (But the version I get from Nuget hasn't got that line...)

Comment: Not sure what's going on. When I answered this question, the Google Code repository did not have `paramNames.Remove("Id");`. Very odd.

Comment: if you are on FW 4.5 this is possible
dynamic objHitEntry = new ExpandoObject();

                    objHitEntry.CompanyId = DismantlerId;
                    objHitEntry.NumHits = 1;
                    objHitEntry.PostKod = PostCode;

                    db.Hits.Insert(objHitEntry);